# Is my process is right of $\int_{}^{} e^{-2x}\cdot\cos{4x} dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Question :
$$\int_{}^{} e^{-2x}\cdot\cos{4x}  dx $$
My process :
 Let $$I = \int_{}^{} e^{-2x}\cdot\cos{4x}  dx   \quad ....[1]$$
$$I = cos{4x}\int_{}^{} e^{-2x} dx-\int_{}^{}(\frac{dx}{dt} cos4x\int_{}^{}e^{-2x}dx)  dx$$
$$I = \frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{-2} -\int_{}^{} 2e^{-2x}sin4x   dx$$
$$I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{2} -2[sin4x\int_{}^{} e^{-2x}- \int_{}^{}(\frac{dx}{dt} sin4x\int_{}^{}e^{-2x}dx)  dx]$$
$$I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{2} -2[\frac{sin4xe^{-2x}}{-2}- \int_{}^{}(4 cos4x\frac{e^{-2x}}{-2}dx)  dx]$$
$$I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{2} -e^{-2x}sin4x - 2I  \quad ....from [1]$$
then ,
$$3I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{2} -e^{-2x}sin4x  $$
$$I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{6} -\frac{e^{-2x}sin4x}{3}  $$
Is my process is okay , i want to know that can we do it more easily .

Comment: Looks correct. Certainly the process is correct.

Comment: Can we do it more easily ?

Comment: Other than minor things like linear $u$-subs, not really. If it was an integral from $0$ to $\infty$, you could know the answer by memory (as the Laplace Transform, $F(s)$) of $\cos(4x)$ evaluated at $s=2$.

Comment: if it is indefinite integral, so I want to learn the process.

Comment: I don't understand. Your answer shows you understand the process. There are only a couple ways to do it differently from scratch. One is to perform a simple $u$ sub to make the constants nicer. The other is to switch the order. In your case, you differentiated the trig functions and integrate the exponential; you could have done two integration by parts by differentiating the exponential and integrating the trig functions. Each way, you get a bounce back effect. This is how the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Like this
$$\int e^{-2x}\cos{4x}dx=\Re \int e^{(-2+4i)x}dx$$

Comment: Excellent hint!

Comment: I should note that your hint only works for the real integral. If we want the complex anti-derivative, we could instead use $\cos(z) = \frac12·(\exp(iz)+\exp(-iz))$.

Comment: Yes,you are right.

Answer (score 1):

In the last step you must get:
$$I = -\frac{cos4x\cdot e^{-2x}}{2} \color{red}+e^{-2x}sin4x - \color{red}4I  \quad ....from [1]$$
Hence the answer:
$$I=-\frac1{10}e^{-2x}\cos 4x+\frac15\sin 4x+C.$$
Alternatively, you can guess the final answer in the form:
$$\int e^{-2x}\cos 4x dx=Ae^{-2x}\cos 4x+Be^{-2x}\sin 4x+C \iff \\
(Ae^{-2x}\cos 4x+Be^{-2x}\sin 4x+C)'=e^{-2x}\cos 4x \iff \\
-2Ae^{-2x}\cos 4x-4Ae^{-2x}\sin 4x-2Be^{-2x}\sin 4x+4Be^{-2x}\cos 4x=e^{-2x}\cos 4x \iff \\
\begin{cases}-2A+4B=1\\ -4A-2B=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow A=-\frac1{10},B=\frac15.$$

Comment: awsome , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is correct, but there are some mistakes because you should get
$$\frac{e^{-2x}(2\sin(4x)-\cos(4x))}{10}+c$$
An hint to do it more easily is to set $y:=-2x$, so you have $\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\text{d}y$ and
$$\int e^{-2x} \cos(4x) \text{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{y} \cos (2y) \text{d}y$$
I have used the fact that $\cos$ is even.

Comment: can you show me process ? I am just confused ?

Comment: What process? The calculations or the substitution?

Comment: Calculation , in short .

Comment: The calculations are long, you have to practice them yourself to improve. Just try them being very careful, these iterated integration by parts can give a lot of trouble with signs and calculation mistakes.
Using the substitution that I've suggested you they are easier.